# How to set log format by level?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am using more than debug level. In other words,debug,info,warn,error  Printed out in scrren
I would like to **make different format by log level** in logback.xml.

Format of debug level is **%-5level:%msg%n**
Format of info level is **%-5level.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}:%msg%n**

Is it possble to make different format by level(debug,info....)?

This is my logback.xml.

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30">
 <!--debug level format-->
 <appender name="STDOUT_DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.out</target>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-5level:%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
 <!--info level format-->
 <appender name="STDOUT_INFO" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.out</target>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-5level.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}:%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- I don't know How to set-->

</configuration>
```

Comment: I think that you're XML is missing a `</appender>`

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to add </appender>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your [custom layout](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#writingYourOwnLayout) extending [LayoutBase](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/LayoutBase.html) to have the maximum flexibility.

You need to rewrite the code of the `doLayout` method

```
public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
    switch (event.getLevel()) {
        ... // Your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it. It is working well. Thank you